# Ruby on Rails: permission denied when using "rails generate controller welcome"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I used Ruby on Rails on Red Hat server. 
When I trying to generate a controller file, I got this error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-22-128 testApp4]$ rails generate controller welcome
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/server.rb:22:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/spring/fea371aaf9d69cfa58bd12f69b3f1bf6.pid (Errno::EACCES)
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/server.rb:22:in `open'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/server.rb:22:in `open'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/server.rb:22:in `initialize'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/server.rb:14:in `new'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/server.rb:14:in `boot'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:43:in `block in boot_server'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:41:in `fork'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:41:in `boot_server'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:24:in `call'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:23:in `call'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/testApp4/bin/spring:16:in `require'
from /home/ec2-user/testApp4/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I solved that problem by running

```
sudo chmod -R 1777 /tmp
```

hope this helps other people like me who would prefer not having to deactivate the spring gem

Comment: If you are on a shared system, 777 will give all other users read and write access to those files... not a good idea.

Comment: Was not helpful for m

Comment: For me it was showing error:
 Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /run/user/1000

Fixed it after running
> sudo chmod -R 1777  /run/user/

Answer (score 12):

It needs ownership to write the re-write the pid for each server start.

I had to run it with my full local path & sudo

$ sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/MyName/Desktop/projects/my_project/tmp/

Answer (score 6):

I took a look at the library that's trying to write the pid file, `lib/spring/env.rb`.

The function in question tries to create a temporary directory at the same location each time unless the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is set:

`path = Pathname.new(File.join(ENV['XDG_RUNTIME_DIR'] || Dir.tmpdir, "spring"))`

Setting said variable to a unique directory does the trick for me:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/`whoami`
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing permission for tmp folder to writable . run `chmod 777 tmp/`

Comment: I ran chmod 777 tmp/, and the problem still exists.

Comment: `(sudo) chmod 1777 /tmp`, not `777`, nor `tmp/`.

Comment: @DMKE I run sudo chmod 1777 /tmp. But the problem still exist. Also I got the same error when I type rails console

Comment: Do you have the same or similar problems, when you remove the `spring` gem from your Gemfile, run the `bundle` command and try generating a controller again?

Comment: @DMKE you genius！！ remove the spring and run it again. Now everything works normal! Thank you so much! But What exactly spring do? is it a must for rails? how can I fixed this problem?

Comment: Spring is an application preloader. See [GitHub project](https://github.com/rails/spring).

Comment: Well, it's not the solution for the problem, just a mere workaround.

Comment: Is there any way to resolve this problem? I am also searching the web for it. @DMKE

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I do not use the spring gem.

Comment: @DMKE `1777` won't solve the problem, but `777` will, because `/tmp/spring` was probably created by another user, and the `sticky bit` will prevent others from removing this directory. Not sure if this is a bug in the `spring` gem, since I've not used this gem. Maybe submitting a bug report will be a good idea?

Comment: No, changing the permissions on `/tmp` won't solve the problem. But you **do** want to have the sticky bit on `/tmp`, or you may risk the security of your system. IMHO Spring should use the application's `tmp` directory (i.e. `Rails.root.join('tmp')`, not [`Dir.tmpdir`](https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/master/lib/spring/env.rb#L35))…

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue when working on a Rails 6 application in Ubuntu 20.04.

Each time I run the command `rails assets:clobber` to remove the old assets in `public/assets` completely, I get the error:

> errno::enotempty: directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir

> errno::eacces: permission denied @ apply2files

And the logs pointed the path to the file causing it, which in my a case was the `public/packs/manifest.json` file.

I tried deleting it or changing permission but nothing worked. I also tried deleting the `tmp` directory in the project, but it did not work.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I listed all the files and directories in that directory using the `ls -lh` command, which gave me this output:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 promisechukwuenyem promisechukwuenyem 1.7K Oct  6 20:29 404.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 promisechukwuenyem promisechukwuenyem 1.7K Oct  6 20:29 422.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 promisechukwuenyem promisechukwuenyem 1.6K Oct  6 20:29 500.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 promisechukwuenyem promisechukwuenyem    0 Oct  6 20:29 apple-touch-icon.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 promisechukwuenyem promisechukwuenyem    0 Oct  6 20:29 apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
drwxr-xr-x 3 promisechukwuenyem promisechukwuenyem 4.0K Oct 13 09:20 armstrong_tools
-rw-rw-r-- 1 promisechukwuenyem promisechukwuenyem    0 Oct  6 20:29 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x 3 root               root               4.0K Oct  8 13:06 packs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 promisechukwuenyem promisechukwuenyem   99 Oct  6 20:29 robots.txt
```

I realized that the permissions for the files and directories were fine, however, the `packs` directory had `root` ownership which was seperate from persmission of other files and directories:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root               root               4.0K Oct  8 13:06 packs
```

I simply ran the command below to change the ownership from root to promisechukwuenyem:

```
sudo chown -R promisechukwuenyem:promisechukwuenyem packs/
```

Now when I ran the command `rails assets:clobber` to remove the old assets in `public/assets` completely, it worked just fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score -1):

Or,

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/${id -u}
```

to change this system variable. `id -u` returns your UID(user id), which is the dir name where you have access to write/read under `/run/user/`.

Answer (score -1):

I am getting this type of error(permission denied @ apply2files) when using `rails server`.

`sudo rails server` solve my problem.

Comment: Starting rails with `sudo` is not recommendable. It does work, but it also gives the rails application superuser access, which is a security issue.