# Errno::EACCES in one of the equal RoR projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, cpanel, permission-denied

On my my VPS with cpanel (CentOs) I have two rails projects on different virtual hosts served by Passenger.
The second project is a branch of first, so now they are equal.

Directories of them are:

```
/home/web/public_html/msystem
/home/web/public_html/msystem2
```

Settings in httpd.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost My.host.IP.adress:80>
        ServerName msystem.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.msystem.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/web/public_html/msystem
        CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/msystem.mydomain.com combined
        CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/msystem.mydomain.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/web/public_html/msystem/cgi-bin/
        Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/web/msystem.mydomain.com/*.conf"
    </VirtualHost>
```

/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/web/msystem.mydomain.com/msystem.conf:

```
    DocumentRoot /home/web/public_html/msystem/public/
    <Directory /home/web/public_html/msystem/public/>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
```

I removed all standard cpanel lines. The second VirtualHost is the same, except replacing `msystem -> msystem2`.

*The first project works, the second no.*

There is a Delayed Job in project. And in both projects I set my logger in `initializers/delayed_job.rb`:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', 'dj.log'))
```

**The second project raises with error:**

> Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/web/public_html/msystem2/log/dj.log (Errno::EACCES)

This `dj.log` in both projects has equal permissions:

```
# ls -l msystem/log/dj.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody 10604043 Aug  7 12:34 msystem/log/dj.log
# ls -l msystem2/log/dj.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody 66 Aug  8 09:25 msystem2/log/dj.log
```

Passenger on error page says that he runs by nobody:nobody user.

> User and groups
>   uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody)

I read many topics on stackoverflow.com about this error. I tryed to change owner to root or permissions to 777. Tryed to restart Apache, Passenger.

First works, second not. What is it? May be I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

This question has an answer:

[Ruby on Rails: permission denied when using "rails generate controller welcome"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822491/ruby-on-rails-permission-denied-when-using-rails-generate-controller-welcome#comment36652515_23822697)

```
chmod 1644 msystem2/log
```