# Error when trying openning console rails in prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I'm using `rails 4.2.0`
I'm using ruby : `ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]`
and rbenv :  `rbenv 0.4.0-129-g7e0e85b`

when I'm trying to open `rails c` in console in production, I have the following error :

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/env.rb:69:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/spring/71079e88c49df6873d86594ca3ada123.pid (Errno::EACCES)
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/env.rb:69:in `open'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/env.rb:69:in `open'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/env.rb:69:in `server_running?'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:25:in `call'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:23:in `call'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /var/www/site/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:3:in `load'
  from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I have update bundle, but nothing change. What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: permission denied when using "rails generate controller welcome"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822491/ruby-on-rails-permission-denied-when-using-rails-generate-controller-welcome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix by :
    sudo chmod -R 1777 /tmp

and reboot spring.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the spring gem inside your production group?

Spring should be inside test and dev only. eg.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'spring'
end
```